Dealing with NaN using Cubic Spline from Scipy
I am attempting to use cubic spline interpolation for a data set (as shown). CubicSpline function requires all numbers to be finite, how can I use it to fill in each NaN value using interpolation?
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['t'] = np.arange(1,11)
n = np.nan
df['r'] = [0, n, n, 0.5, n, 0.3, n, n, n, 0.4]
cs = CubicSpline(df['t'], df['r'])

This spits out the error "y must contain only finite values."
I have tried replacing all NaN with 0s, but this returns a spline that is centered around 0 and jumps up for each known value.

Pass all the non-NaN values to the interpolator.

I would suggest dropping NA values, fitting the spline to the non-NA values, and using fillna to replace the NA values with the spline-interpolated values.
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['t'] = np.arange(1,11)
n = np.nan
df['r'] = [0, n, n, 0.5, n, 0.3, n, n, n, 0.4]
df_no_nan = df.dropna()
cs = CubicSpline(df_no_nan['t'], df_no_nan['r'])
df['r'] = df['r'].fillna(pd.Series(cs(df['t']), df['t'].index))
print(df)

Output:
    t         r
0   1  0.000000
1   2  0.339259
2   3  0.489444
3   4  0.500000
4   5  0.420370
5   6  0.300000
6   7  0.188333
7   8  0.134815
8   9  0.188889
9  10  0.400000

